# Looking for an idiom describing age

Tags: idioms

I'm translating a script for a cartoon into English. In one of the scenes a grandpa's talking to his granddaughter. It goes something like this:

*GRANDPA*

*Indeed! I have forgotten! Apparently, your grandpa’s getting **a bit long in the tooth**. Anyway, would you give your old grandpa a hug?*

*She turns around slowly. She sees her grandpa **with long teeth**. She rubs her eyes and the vision’s gone.*

Seems clear, right? The thing is in my native tongue we don't say "long in the tooth", we say something along the lines of "be like a mushroom" (= be old). And, unfortunately, that's what you see when you're watching the original episode - a grandpa covered in mushrooms (not with long teeth).

As there's no way the producers are ever going to agree to change the original scene and make it work for the English audience, I need to come up with an idiom combining **old age** and **mushrooms** (a tree with fungi, possibly?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Getting a bit mouldy in his old age?

Comment: Hmm, how can we possible link "mushrooms" to "experiencing hallucinations"? Stumps me.

Comment: @DanBron: We're not going there, Dan. It's for small kids. Let them finish their preschools before they get to know Psilocybe cubensis. :)

Comment: There's the other old joke about Grandpa being a Fun Guy ha ha ha

Comment: What's so bad about just directly translating it? Sure, it might lose some context, but then again, I'm not sure little kids understand what "long in the tooth" means either.

Comment: @Mynamite: "Mouldy"... Sounds interesting. Can a senile person be described as "mouldy"? And is mould easily associated with mushrooms? I mean I know it's fungus, but is it (fungus-mushroom) clear for a 5-year-old?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: The direct translation will make no sense whatsoever for anyone. Think about it - the Grandad says: "I'm getting old and forgetful", and she sees him covered with mushrooms... I mean what the heck? :) Of course, I can resort to making a footnote and telling them to deal with it themselves, but, well, that's the last solution on my list.

Comment: @Mynamite: Can you eleborate on the joke?

Comment: I don't know if 5 year olds can reasonably be expected to associate mould with mushrooms, I imagine they would only encounter it with mouldy bread or cheese. I think it would be derogatory to call an old person 'mouldy'. At a bit of a tangent there's 'ripe old age' or 'past his best', but again I don't really think a 5 year old would interpret this as literally covered in mushrooms.

Comment: @jules *Fungi* and *fun guy* are homophones.

Comment: Joke - Why did the mushroom get invited to all the parties? Because he's a fungi (mispronounced). Edit: @ElliottFrisch I would pronounce it with a short 'i', so a bad joke is even worse!

Comment: @jules I meant a more literal translation, mushroom part and all. If the grandfather says "I'm getting old and forgetful" and grows some mushrooms, then it won't make sense, but if he says "I'm getting old and forgetful like a mushroom", then I think that's better than trying to use wordplay to get there. Which are kids more likely to understand: a direct translation, or some kind of metaphor about mold that not many people use?

Comment: @Mynamite, and Elliot - Now I get it ;) I like it. I don't know if it's gonna work, but I like it.

Comment: "Indeed! I have forgotten! But your grandpa’s still a fun guy! Anyway, would you give your old grandpa a hug?"

Comment: @KevinWorkman: You do have a point there. That's the second last solution. ;) I guess, however, I'd need to work on the "like a mushroom" bit to make it more old age-y. You know, old-wrinkled-mushroom (?).

Comment: @Mynamite: It's clever :) I'll run it through the producers :) I can see them going no-no on that, but what the heck :)

Comment: OK :) The joke itself is a mouldy one (but then kids love those, never having heard them before). Mark Twain:[...informed her that "chestnut" was a figurative term meaning an aged and mouldy joke. I turned pale at that, for I have made many jokes to pass the weary time, and some of them could have been of that sort...](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst16376_Principles-have-no-real-force-except-when-one-is-well-fed-.aspx). There's a literary character who constantly refers to things as *mouldy* but I can't remember who. I thought it was *Catcher in the Rye* but can't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging Mynamite and StoneyB's observations, if you are stuck with the fungal image, the closest seems like

> *I'm getting so old and mouldy, I'm sprouting mushrooms!*

[Not suggesting actual biological accuracy.]

Comment: Note that if this will be published in the US, the spelling should be _moldy_.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. I deferred to the earlier versions by my Anglo-cohorts.

Comment: Yes. The entire series is in AmE so "moldy" it is.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, mushrooms do not have this connotation in English. Quite the opposite: the proverbial cliche is “springing up like mushrooms”, referring to the sudden appearance of many mushrooms where none grew before.

We do speak of *moss* this way—*moss-covered* implies long inaction—and as Mynamite says *mould*. Would the drawing accommodate either of these?

Comment: I'm afraid the drawing will show your most stereotypical mushroom.

Answer (score 0):

'I'm growing some fungus around the edges.'

Comment: Is it a pun? Is it "getting frayed around the edges"? Hmm... and then he asks for a hug from his granddaughter.

Comment: 'Fungus' is better when speaking in the context of mushrooms.You have to allow a bit of poetic license here.

Comment: But isn't supposed to be funghy? (groan) Not mushroom for laughter there, is there?

Comment: Singular 'fungus' is funnier than 'fungi'and a lot funnier than 'frayed'. We should not forget this is for a cartoon. Technicalities get in the way.